# Запись и чтение файла

Tags: php

Всем привет! Есть файл, который я хочу использовать как мини бд, в котором  храниться 6 записей. Он имеет такой формат :

```
http://sanstorm.ru/top/
Half-Life Portal
default
trylolo
C:\lolo\lolo\kz_top\
C:\lolo\mapcycle.txt
```

Пытаюсь прочитать файл и записать отдельно строки в разные переменные, но не получается!

```
$read = file("config2.php");        
$url=$read[0];  
$server=$read[1];
$template=$read[2];
$password=$read[3];
$topfolder=$read[4];
$maplist=$read[5];
```

Скрипт читает из файла все и записывает в переменные, но как-то это делает странно. Если вывести переменные через `echo`, то они нормально отображаются, но если переменные подставлять в скрипт то они не работают. Точнее, после нужной мне строки добавляется 6 пустых строк. В чем проблемма? Скрипт, которым записывал в файл:

```
$open=fopen("config2.php","w");
$save = "$url\n$namesite\n$template\n$password\n$topfolder\n$maplistfile";
fputs($open, $save);
```

Comment: [почитайте](http://zavu.ru/FXoLqwc/)

Comment: Добавьте вторым параметром в функцию `file`  флаг [FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES](http://php.net/manual/ru/filesystem.constants.php#constant.file-skip-empty-lines). И на всякий случай, добавлять корректный символ конца строки, гораздо удобней константой `PHP_EOL`

Comment: мда... щас бы вопросы 8 летней давности поднимать...

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте вывести весь массив read с помощью `print_r()`. Уверен, все будет не так, как вы ожидали.

Во-первых, почему расширение php а не txt?
Во-вторых, где разбивка текста на массив строк с помощью `strtok()`?

Comment: дело в том что я только начал с php общаться многово не знаю))
1. имеет ли какое-то значение расширение фала (тхт или же рнр) ?
2. Про функцию strok() слышу в перывые (пошел читать php.su :-) )
Спасибо за оперативность ))

Comment: что то я не очень догнал как в моем случае применима эта функция?

Comment: По той же самой причине, почему исходный код си плюс плюс сохраняется с расширением .cpp, не более чем рекомендации... но придерживаясь их, можно избежать много ошибок, особенно актуально в больших проектах, в которых трудятся несколько человек

Comment: Расширение файла изменил, как быть с этой функцией?
Можно пример как должно быть в моем случае?

Comment: можете кстати взглянуть какие ошибки выдает скрипт 
http://sanstorm.ru/top/index.php

Answer (score -1):

1 совет дам не храни данные в файлах! в mysql по таблицам! и надёжнее и удобно! а файлы это старая тема!

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Но вопрос до сих пор актуален!

Answer (score -1):

В строке `$save = "$url\n$namesite\n$template\n$password\n$topfolder\n$maplistfile";`

вместо `\n` впиши `.chr(13).chr(10).` - это и есть коды перевода строк